# How to change grammar detection in ATOM editor

Tags: atom-editor

I'm currently using atom to code with Arduino. It's quite convenient, because you have all your languages in one editor.

When i now create a .ino file, the grammar will detect "C++". I have installed the languages-arduino pack, but it doesn't automatically detect the .ino files.

I saw some suggestion to add `customFileTypes` to the config.cson like this:

```
core:
  customFileTypes:
      "source.arduino": [
        ".ino"
```

But still, when i create a new .ino file it will choose the C++ over the Arduino language.

Do you guys have some ideas on how to choose Arduino over C++?

Comment: Have you tried using `"*.ino"`?

Comment: Try with `ino` (without the dot).